# Mikrotik IPSec Tunnels not working after RouterOS upgrade

Tags: ipsec, l2tp, mikrotik, routeros

We upgraded our RB1100AH2x yesterday from 6.19 to 6.22 and lost our L2TP / IPSec tunnels in the process. The logs are now littered with IPSec errors stating

```
failed to pre-process ph2 packet.
```

In the change log for 6.21 I notice that you can no longer employ a blank value for the Policy Group in the Peer policy. We had originally configured our tunnel this way and I suspect that this is the cause of the errors.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to resolve this issue?

See relevant config below (note that the first entry in the ipsec peer is note relevant - entry "1" is the one I am most concerned about

```
/ip ipsec peer> print
Flags: X - disabled, D - dynamic 
 0 X  address=xx.xx.xx.xx/32 local-address=0.0.0.0 passive=no 
      port=500 auth-method=pre-shared-key secret="redacted" 
      generate-policy=no policy-template-group=*FFFFFFFF 
      exchange-mode=main send-initial-contact=yes 
      nat-traversal=no proposal-check=obey hash-algorithm=md5 
      enc-algorithm=3des dh-group=modp1024 lifetime=1d 
      lifebytes=0 dpd-interval=disable-dpd dpd-maximum-failures=1 

 1  D address=0.0.0.0/0 local-address=0.0.0.0 passive=yes port=500 
      auth-method=pre-shared-key secret="redacted" 
      generate-policy=port-strict policy-template-group=default 
      exchange-mode=main-l2tp send-initial-contact=yes 
      nat-traversal=yes hash-algorithm=sha1 
      enc-algorithm=3des,aes-128,aes-192,aes-256 
      dh-group=modp1024 lifetime=1d dpd-interval=2m 
      dpd-maximum-failures=5 


/ip ipsec proposal> print
Flags: X - disabled, * - default 
 0  * name="default" auth-algorithms=sha1 
      enc-algorithms=3des,aes-256-cbc lifetime=30m 
      pfs-group=modp1024
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the group, which is in the IP/ipsec groups.

Then it will say unknown in the peer tab. After that, it should work.